# How to handle and use RubyGem bundle on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I started learning `Ruby` from (**http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html**) and successfully installed ruby and created a blog folder under htdocs as given in the tutorial.

During the creation of new folder(blog folder) its showing "`Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org`" and installed some bundles with the final message "Your bundle is complete! Use 'bundle show [gemname]' to see....." but when i run the command like "bundle show jquery-rails" it flags message like "Could not locate GemFile" then i searched this file in my computer and found it under 
"`C:\Users\MyComUserName\.gem\specs\rubygems.org%443\quick\Marshal.4.8`".

Now my question is - what i did wrong, and how could i resolve it if i really did something wrong. I am from PHP background so using XAMPP and saving ROR projects too under my HTDOCS folder (`Windows 7` OS im using). How could i use gems or how they are beneficial to me while development. I looked at this article too (**http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/1/**) but unable to get a lot as i am at very initial stage. Kindly guide me as im at very initial step to use RoR, `looking for a descriptive answer with some links to get more hands on RoR`.

(I am from PHP background and aware of MVC).

Please check screenshots

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdnUK.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzk8Y.jpg]

Comment: Try doing `gem install jquery-rails` and then `bundle show jquery-rails` and see what happens.

Comment: @Jon what is the use of re installing if its already get installed??? Do i need to install under my blog folder???

Comment: I meant to do it as a test to make sure it installed properly, and yes, you need to be running these in your project `dir`.

Comment: @Jon Yes it works..thx a lot please post this as your answer so that i can make it green :) .... Although i hava little query that ---> I run the command ""gem install jquery-rails"" from path C:\\xampp\htdocs\ablog>gem install jquery-rails  but installed under "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems" after querying at C:\\xampp\htdocs\ablog>bundle show jquery-rails, i think im missing some path installation specifications for the ruby..if possible kindly throw a light in your answer too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this in your project's directory:

```
gem install jquery-rails
bundle show jquery-rails
```

It seems redundant to install the gem even though it was listed as installing, but it's best to double check.

I'm not sure - and please edit if you know - but I think that rails installs all of your gems in the `ruby/gems` folder and looks for them when you need them. Maybe somehow the `jquery-rails` gem was put in the wrong place but installed correctly (hence, no error) and couldn't find it when you ran `bundle show jquery-rails` the first time.

Also, if you are just starting with ruby and rails, I would recommend the free courses offered on [tryruby.org](http://tryruby.org) and [railsforzombies.com](http://railsforzombies.com). They don't cover much, but they give you the basics you need to get things running.

For more detailed and advanced tutorials, check out [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com). He covers a lot of topics and shows a lot of useful tricks in rails.

Best of luck and have fun with Ruby!